# jQuery Datatables strangely wraps the child row content with "<tr>"

Tags: jquery, datatables

Ok so here’s the thing . I’m using jQuery datatable grid with child rows and everything is working fine. The only problem is that when the “.child()” method is called like this “row.child(format(row.data())).show();” it renders a simple paragraph and puts it into the child row(that’s fine), but it also wraps the paragraph in a strange 
“`<tr><td colpspan=”4”></td></tr>`” 
which is not desired and it’s not created by my code. It’s probably a part of the “.child()” method itself and I can’t figure out how to manipulate it . The question is : How can I prevent the paragraph(or any content) rendered by “.format()” method being wrapped in “`<tr><td colpspan=”4”></td></tr>`”
[image] ?

Here is the code :

```
function format (d) {
                return '<p class="custom_paragraph">ok</p>';
    }
```

--

```
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
        $('#gridEntities1 tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = entities_grid.row(tr);

            if(row.child.isShown()){
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else{
                // Open this row
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is `<td colspan=”4”></td>` not colpspan, and it is how it works. It gives you the ability to have some child content in the full width of the table.

Comment: You can only have `<tr>` elements as the direct children of `<tbody>`. Datatables is taking care of this for you. You still have complete control over how this child row is styled. This extra markup is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , that may not be the proper solution for this, but it worked for me as workaround. I just removed the margin and padding around the paragraph like this :

```
$('.custom_paragraph').closest('td').css({'margin': '0', 'padding': '0'});
```